Fill color between many lines scatter on Plotly JS
I want to fill color to the chart (SPC Chart) 
With the easy data, it can fill normally. However, with this sample data it fills not well, the range color fill looks quite stupid :((((
Please, refer to the link and review it. Can anybody help me to fill same as expected picture.

The expected layout that draw with AmChart



function generateData() {
  const data = [
    "12.466",
    "12.739",
    "13.491",
    "13.936",
    "14.339",
    "14.955",
    "15.375",
    "15.842",
    "16.163",
    "16.864",
    "17.541",
    "17.763",
    "17.755",
    "17.755",
    "17.602",
    "17.815",
    "17.086",
    "17.561",
    "17.422",
    "17.487",
    "17.499",
    "17.611",
    "17.866",
    "17.451",
    "17.37",
    "17.766",
    "17.529",
    "17.158",
    "17.28",
    "17.626",
    "17.625",
    "17.594",
    "17.376",
    "17.712",
    "17.879",
    "17.073",
    "17.202",
    "17.534",
    "17.374",
    "17.822"
  ];
  const timestamps = [
    "2024-09-10 18:06:55",
    "2024-09-10 18:06:56",
    "2024-09-10 18:06:57",
    "2024-09-10 18:06:58",
    "2024-09-10 18:06:59",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:00",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:01",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:02",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:03",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:04",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:05",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:06",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:07",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:08",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:09",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:10",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:11",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:12",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:14",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:15",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:16",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:17",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:18",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:19",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:20",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:21",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:22",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:23",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:24",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:25",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:26",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:27",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:28",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:29",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:30",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:31",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:32",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:33",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:34",
    "2024-09-10 18:07:36"
  ];
  const usl = [
    "",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "13",
    "",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1",
    "18.1"
  ];
  const ucl = [
    "",
    "12.5",
    "12",
    "12",
    "12",
    "12",
    "12",
    "12",
    "12",
    "12",
    "",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9",
    "17.9"
  ];
  const lcl = [
    "",
    "11.5",
    "10",
    "10",
    "10",
    "10",
    "10",
    "10",
    "10",
    "10",
    "",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5",
    "16.5"
  ];
  const lsl = [
    "",
    "10.5",
    "9",
    "9",
    "9",
    "9",
    "9",
    "9",
    "9",
    "9",
    "",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1",
    "1"
  ];

  return {
    timestamps,
    data,
    usl,
    ucl,
    lcl,
    lsl
  };
}

const { timestamps, data, usl, ucl, lcl, lsl } = generateData();

function createFillBetweenTraces(xData, ucl, lcl, usl, lsl) {
  const traces = [];

  let x = [];
  let yUsl = [];
  let yLsl = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
    if (usl[i] !== null && lsl[i] !== null) {
      x.push(xData[i]);
      yUsl.push(usl[i]);
      yLsl.push(lsl[i]);
    } else if (x.length > 0) {
      traces.push({
        x: x.slice(),
        y: yLsl.slice(),
        mode: "lines",
        line: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        showlegend: false
      });
      traces.push({
        x: x.slice(),
        y: yUsl.slice(),
        fill: "tonexty",
        fillcolor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 1.0)",
        line: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        showlegend: false
      });

      x = [];
      yUsl = [];
      yLsl = [];
    }
  }

  if (x.length > 0) {
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yLsl,
      mode: "lines",
      line: {
        color: "transparent"
      },
      showlegend: false
    });
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yUsl,
      fill: "tonexty",
      fillcolor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 1.0)",
      line: {
        color: "transparent"
      },
      showlegend: false
    });
  }

  x = [];
  let yUcl = [];
  let yLcl = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
    if (ucl[i] !== null && lcl[i] !== null) {
      x.push(xData[i]);
      yUcl.push(ucl[i]);
      yLcl.push(lcl[i]);
    } else if (x.length > 0) {
      traces.push({
        x: x.slice(),
        y: yLcl.slice(),
        mode: "lines",
        line: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        showlegend: false
      });
      traces.push({
        x: x.slice(),
        y: yUcl.slice(),
        mode: "lines",
        fill: "tonexty",
        fillcolor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)",
        line: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        showlegend: false
      });
      x = [];
      yUcl = [];
      yLcl = [];
    }
  }

  if (x.length > 0) {
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yLcl,
      mode: "lines",
      line: {
        color: "transparent"
      },
      showlegend: false
    });
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yUcl,
      mode: "lines",
      fill: "tonexty",
      fillcolor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)",
      line: {
        color: "transparent"
      },
      showlegend: false
    });
  }

  return traces;
}

let fillBetweenTraces = [];

function createPlot(xData, xAxisType) {
  fillBetweenTraces = createFillBetweenTraces(xData, ucl, lcl, usl, lsl);

  const trace1 = {
    x: xData,
    y: data,
    mode: "lines+markers",
    name: "Value",
    marker: {
      color: "blue"
    },
    line: {
      color: "blue"
    }
  };

  const trace2 = {
    x: xData,
    y: usl,
    mode: "lines",
    name: "USL",
    line: {
      dash: "dash",
      color: "red"
    }
  };

  const trace3 = {
    x: xData,
    y: ucl,
    mode: "lines",
    name: "UCL",
    line: {
      dash: "dot",
      color: "orange"
    }
  };

  const trace4 = {
    x: xData,
    y: lcl,
    mode: "lines",
    name: "LCL",
    line: {
      dash: "dot",
      color: "orange"
    }
  };

  const trace5 = {
    x: xData,
    y: lsl,
    mode: "lines",
    name: "LSL",
    line: {
      dash: "dash",
      color: "red"
    }
  };

  const dataToPlot = [
    ...fillBetweenTraces,
    trace1,
    trace2,
    trace3,
    trace4,
    trace5
  ];
  /* const dataToPlot = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5] */ const layout = {
    title: "Scatter Plot with Control and Specification Limits",
    xaxis: {
      type: "date",
      tickformat: "%Y-%m-%d<br>%H:%M:%S"
    }
  };

  Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", dataToPlot, layout);
}

createPlot(timestamps, "timestamp");
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Scatter Plot with Plotly</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="myDiv"></div>

</html>




I implemented the createFillBetweenTraces function. Worked as expected


function createFillBetweenTraces(xData, ucl, lcl, usl, lsl) {
  let x = [];
  const traces = [];

  // USL LSL
  x = [];
  let yUsl = [],
    yLsl = [];

  xData.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (usl[i] !== "" && lsl[i] !== "") {
      x.push(xData[i]);
      yUsl.push(usl[i]);
      yLsl.push(lsl[i]);
    } else if (x.length > 0) {
      traces.push({
        x: x,
        y: yLsl,
        mode: 'lines',
        line: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        showlegend: false,
        hoverinfo: "none"
      });

      traces.push({
        x: x,
        y: yUsl,
        fill: 'tonexty',
        fillcolor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)',
        line: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        showlegend: false,
        hoverinfo: "none"
      });

      xData.slice(i);
      x = [];
      yUsl = [];
      yLsl = [];
    }
  })

  if (x.length > 0) {
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yLsl,
      mode: 'lines',
      line: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      showlegend: false,
      hoverinfo: "none"
    });
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yUsl,
      mode: 'lines',
      fill: 'tonexty',
      fillcolor: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.3)',
      line: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      showlegend: false,
      hoverinfo: "none"
    });
  }

  x = [];
  let yUcl = [],
    yLcl = [];

  xData.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (ucl[i] !== "" && lcl[i] !== "") {
      x.push(xData[i]);
      yUcl.push(ucl[i]);
      yLcl.push(lcl[i]);
    } else if (x.length > 0) {
      traces.push({
        x: x,
        y: yLcl,
        mode: 'lines',
        line: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        showlegend: false,
        hoverinfo: "none"
      });
      traces.push({
        x: x,
        y: yUcl,
        fill: 'tonexty',
        fillcolor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)',
        line: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
        showlegend: false,
        hoverinfo: "none"
      });

      xData.slice(i);
      x = [];
      yUcl = [];
      yLcl = [];
    }
  })

  if (x.length > 0) {
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yLcl,
      mode: 'lines',
      line: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      showlegend: false,
      hoverinfo: "none"
    });
    traces.push({
      x: x,
      y: yUcl,
      mode: 'lines',
      fill: 'tonexty',
      fillcolor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)',
      line: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      showlegend: false,
      hoverinfo: "none"
    });
  }

  return traces;
}



